# Open with Explorer prompts for credentials

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, dms

We have a DMS in SharePoint, When user tries to "Open With Explorer", it asks for credentials. We are already having site under trusted sites and automatic logon is also enabled. When user types in the credentials, it works. Next thing is when user try again by closing and reopening IE, it works fine this time, without asking for credentials. Problem occurs again, when user restarts his machine. Once again, IE asks for credentials. and the same thing goes on.

I just want to know if this is default behaviour for sharepoint to ask for credentials for the first time, each time machine is turned on? Any microsoft article on that?

Many thanks.

Comment: It's certainly not the default behavior. It's works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I solved editing the registry as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943280). Windows Explorer uses WebClient service to open Sharepoint links. This service doesn't follow Internet Explorer Trusted and Intranet Sites but classify as Intranet only URLs without dots in the hostname.
To change this behaviour you need to create a Multi-String subkey named AuthForwardServerList in this location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters
```

Then fill the value with URLs like this example:

```
https://*.Contoso.com
http://*.dns.live.com
*.microsoft.com
```

Restart the WebClient service and enjoy.

Comment: Please, do not rely on links alone, they may go defunct and render your answer useless. Instead, please, add enough detail to make your answer as self-contained as possible.

Comment: this should be accepted as answer, this resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if the Webclient service set to start "Automatically" instead of "Manually"?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2629108

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior for our organization (running SharePoint 2013). Each day the user has to supply credentials to 'Open with Explorer'. Once successful you can open any other Library without issue but it will reset the next day.